# Changing colour using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

What I'm trying to do is to use onmouseover and onmouseout to change the colour of one of the eyes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<svg height="400" width="500">
<circle cx="200" cy="200" r="180" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="yellow" />
<ellipse cx="130" cy="140" rx="25" ry="40" style="fill:blue" stroke="black"  stroke-width="2"/>
<ellipse cx="270" cy="140" rx="25" ry="40" style="fill:blue" stroke="black"  stroke-width="2" />
<rect x="180" y="200" width="50" height="50" style="fill:blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
<polyline points="100,250 150,320 280,320 330,250 270,300 160,300 100,250" style="fill:blue"   stroke="black";stroke-width="2" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
function onmouseover(evt) {
document.getElementById('eye1').setAttribute("fill", col);
function onmouseout(evt) {
document.getElementById('eye1').setAttribute("fill", col);
}
]]>
</script>

<ellipse cx="130" cy="140" rx="25" ry="40" style="fill:blue" stroke="black"  stroke-width="2"     id="eye1" onmouseover="changeColor('red')" 
onmouseout="changeColor('green')"   
/>

</svg>
</html>
```

Comment: put the code on fiddle to test

Comment: a couple of points, changeColor function you reference does not exist and you have a missing `}` in your js. Also i would move the js out of the actual js

Comment: Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/nirodhasoftware/ad4cybx7/